# ¿Cómo hacer un 'cast' a String con un valor recogido de un diccionario [String:Any]?

Tags: ios, swift

Tengo un diccionario con nombre resultado de tipo [String:Any] con los valores recogidos de un JSON. Tal como:

```
["key1": 1, "key2": Pepe, "key3": 147]
```

A la hora de recoger el valor 1 de la `key1` hago lo siguiente,

```
var valor1: String    
self.valor1 = resultado?["key1"] as! String
```

lo quiero hacer como String pero me sale un error de tipo:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFBoolean' (0x10766c608) to
>   'NSString' (0x103d3ec60).

Si lo hago como:

```
self.valor1 = resultado?["key1"] as! Bool
```

Lo recoge pero como `true`

¿Cómo puedo hacer un casting a String para que me aparezca 1 y no `true`?

Comment: Cómo estás pasando el JSON a [String:Any]? Creo que ahí puede estar el problema realmente

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema puede ser que 1 no es un `String` en el diccionario. Swift detecta 1 como `Bool` pero no puede hacer el casting a String.

Tienes dos opciones, o bien cambiar el diccionario para que sea "1" o bien lo recoges como `Int` y haces el casting a `String` con `String(numero)`

Comment: En el caso de la key2 el valor es pepe no está entre comillas y si que me permite recogerlo como string. No entiendo porque con el 1 ese carácter Swift se empeña en pensar que es un bool y  no lo trata como si fuera un carácter tipo string